# How can I submit a form right after a user chooses a picture?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, cgi

I have a form and I'm trying to figure out how I can submit the form after the user uploads a picture and it is verified that it is a picture. I am trying to use javascript to verify the image being uploaded.

Comment: How is the user uploading the picture?  Normally, they have to submit the form to upload the picture in the first place...

Comment: Can you be a little more detailed please. Will you be using JavaScript to verify the picture or PHP?

Comment: by using `<input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="file" />`

Comment: With php you cannot check the file until it's uploaded. You can upload it asynchroniously within an `<iframe>` and afterwards send back javascript to do whatever you wish

Comment: how could I "send back javascript"? (Code wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function submitFormAfterImageCheck()
    {
        if(/(\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.tiff)$/.test(document.getElementById("myFile").value))
        {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
        else
        {
            alert("you can only upload an image");
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<input id="myFile" type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck();" />
```

Comment: I have added the javascript code to the head part of the document and added the following code: `<form id="uploadpic" method=post name=upform action="/cgi-bin/upload.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" onchange="submitFormAfterImageCheck();" />   
</form>` but it won't submit

Comment: What's the URL? I could write it exactly as needed for ya :)

Comment: oops! I was missing a `)` at the end of the `if()`

Comment: awesome that worked except now, no matter what I upload, I'm getting the alert "you can only upload an image". I've tried .png, .tif, etc.

Comment: you can test if this function works `function submitFormAfterImageCheck() {alert(this.value==''?"not working":"working");}`

Comment: yes, that was a good idea. But whatever I uploaded seemed to go through as I kept getting "working"

Comment: No problem! The funny part is... I just did this on my site a month or two ago, and I totally forgot what I did. Just wondering... what's your reasoning for this? I did it so that self conscious users can't really back out after selecting their artwork :P. They're kind of expecting that opportunity to back out after they've already selected their image (the opportunity to NOT hit the submit button ;P)

Comment: haha thats kinda sneaky, I am doing this because it's more "web 2.0" the submit button was so 2000. lol no but I've built a social network: http://friendsconnect.org/ and am aiming for a sexier/ quicker settings page.

Comment: oh cool! I just signed up :) Looks nice. I have a few UX suggestions for you if you're interested.

Comment: yeah but can u message me on FB or something so we dont take up to much room on this page lol

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Iframe to handle the upload

```
<iframe src="upload.php" id="uploadHandler"></iframe>
```

and javascript to handle uploading/receiving status

```
var form = document.getElementById("avatar_form");
var inpUpload = document.getElementById("upload_button");
var fileSelector = document.getElementById("file_browser");
var uploadHandler = document.getElementById('uploadHandler');

inpUpload.onclick = function() {

    form.target = uploadHandler;
    uploadHandler.onload = function() {
        alert(uploadHandler.document.body.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

and in the php file `upload.php`: check the $_FILES array if the uploaded file is ok and echo some response like:

```
$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "png", "gif");
if (in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES['file_browser']['filename'])), $allowed_extensions)) {
    echo "upload OK";
}
else {
    echo "invalid file";
}
```

not tested ... yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check file extension on the client side and then decide whether to trigger submit for the form like so (jQuery style):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#fileDivId').change(function(){
            $this = $(this);
                if ($.inArray($this.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']) != -1) {
                    $this.parent().trigger('submit');
                }
        });
    });
</script>
    <form action="post.php" method="POST">
        <input type="file" id="fileDivId">
    </form>
```

But there are some weak points here:

1) You **still have to** sanitize your images on server side

2) Not quite sure how $('inputId').val() works when input type is "file". For example firefox 4 returns file name, but if I remember correctly, IE will return full path of the file (C:\Docs\Img\etc), and furthermore it might be disabled in some browsers due to security reasons.

3) Getting extension part in my code is not perfect - concider situation: user selects file C:\Doc.img\file_no_ext, it returns "img\file_no_ext"